# nginx: run rails/passenger and wordpress with subfolder permalinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, passenger

I need help with my nginx configuration.
I want to run a rails app and a Wordpress blog under the same domain.
Wordpress should be available under a subfolder/path.

Both are already up and running, but I cannot access blog posts.
Here is my current configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name my-secret-host.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_min_instances 1;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /var/www/rails-app/current/public;

    # Wordpress 
    location /news {
      alias /var/www/wordpress/;
      index index.php ;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
      location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      }
   }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
```

I tried a lot. 
With this variation the Rails app works as expected. Wordpress is also up and running, the admin area and the index page (/) are available. 
But if I call a permalink to a post like `http://my-secret-host.com/news/2017/10/permalink-test-post/` the rails app responds with an error.

Maybe the solution is stupid and simple, but all my attempts ended in other problems and errors.

Moving the rails config into a `location /` block didn't change anything.

With disabled rails configuration I get another error, the path to `index.php` is not properly configured.

```
[error] 7705#7705: *7 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 87.133.34.209, server: my-host.com, request: "GET /news/2017/10/test234/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my-host.com", referrer: "http://my-host.com/news/"
```

What you see above is a activated/linked configuration file in `nginx/sites-available/`.
I unlinked `sites-available/default`, created my own and didn't change anything in `nginx.conf`– expect of the rails-passenger include.

Comment: Add `passenger_enabled off;` to the location block, https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_enabled